# Как перемещаться по дочерним каталогам используя content Uri путь?

Tags: android, kotlin

Допустим я получил Uri с помощью этого метода

```
val documentContract = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(urisList.last().treeUri,
                        urisList.last().treeId)
```

Это Uri корня SD карты, но как получить доступ на запись например в папку Android (SD/Android/) или дочерние каталоги (SD/Android/..)?
Пробовал так получать Uri дочерних каталогов

```
val cursorDocumentsContract = contentResolver.query(documentContract, arrayOf(
                    DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID),
                    null, null, null)!!
                while (cursorDocumentsContract.moveToNext()) {
                    if (cursorDocumentsContract.getString(0).equals(file.name)) {
                        val doc = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(documentContract, cursorDocumentsContract.getString(1))
                }
             }
```

Но папка создается всеравно в корне SD карты.
Пробовал так

```
DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, doc)!!.createDirectory("Folder")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам себе отвечу. Папку нужно тоже создавать через класс DocumentsContract. Например:
`DocumentsContract.createDocument(contentResolver, doc, "vnd.android.document/directory", "Folder Name")`

С файлами тоже самое, требуется всего лишь нужный MIME Type указать. Через DocumentFile создать что либо в дочерних каталогах по Uri полученных от DocumentContract не получается.